# Can I fool a HP SE1102 server into thinking its fan works?

Tags: fan, cooling

One of my servers fan stopped working. The server is an ancient HP SE1102 server (special edition). Fan picture (includes serials and what not): [image: fan picture]. The server starts.. does it's thing and when gets to the power on self test(or post screen) it immediately shuts down.. when I remove the fan completely it shows that fan from x location is missing.

Its connector is 9 wire - 5 pin. 
[image]

The wire colors are: black, grey ; yellow, red ; green ; white, blue ; orange.
("," means wires in one pin hole. ";" means another pin hole)

Since the specific fan is rare nowadays and costs a bit my question is what exactly does each wire do and is there a way to fool the server to understand that the fan is there and working? Since there isn't a problem with enough cooling or if there is I can just add some usb fans or build some diy extra cooling.

Comment: [Only pinout chart I could find](http://pinoutsguide.com/Motherboard/hp_compaq_case_fan_pinout.shtml) Red and black wires are usually 12v and gnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it sometimes is simpler to say "here's what you need really cheap"
[5 for $25](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/391268962580?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82)

I have done a bit of research into this. It appears to be two fans hooked together.  (The datasheets I found do suggest this as well, being fan1 and fan2)
[Datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/PMD1204PJB1-A-Sunon-Fans-datasheet-126742.pdf)
This being said, I will have to assume some things here going forward because I am unable to comment on posts.

Starting off, You'll need to carefully take some good pictures of all labels and markings on the fan, this is to ensure you don't lose any physical data in the form of a label.

Proceed to separate the fans from each other. I don't have a set of fans myself to show you **how** to do it.  I can only assume that they're held together by a means that could be reversed or defeated.

The first step I'd say is to carefully remove the labels.

If they do not come apart now the second step I will assume would be pulling off the blue things on the right side of the assembly in the picture.  Looking into the holes you **might** find something that could be unscrewed to release one fan from another.

If there is nothing there or there is plastic pins which have been glued in place, you could try drilling the plastic pins out however this is **not** reversible unless you glue new ones in place.

If you cannot get them apart I'll have to guess which wire does what.

If you can get them apart my life and guessing job just got way easier. These fans are **probably** 3 wire fans. Ground, Positive, and PWM wires.  Being a part time PC tech and full time PC enthusiast I've seen a lot of different wiring codes when it comes to wiring a fan from different manufacturers. This being said some particular manufacturers tend to use whatever is in stock to wire their fans... Resulting in a very hard time of guessing which wire does what.  Here's why getting them apart might help.

If you're lucky you'll have a couple small labels that could be pealed back and your circuit board might have a bit of writing on it.  This could tell you which wires are what!
Examples:

zizzydizzymc info/ss/DSCN5146.JPG

zizzydizzymc info/ss/DSCN5154.JPG

Sorry no rep so I can't provide direct links to these high-res images I JUST took of a couple odd-ball fans from my fan box.

Anyway if you have that then you have the power to spoof the fans. How? Just wire up another fan to it (the harness) the way it should be and it has a high chance of working. Make sure to use a 12v rated fan.

Another thing to note is that **possibly** only one fan in the 2 fan section stopped working. Which means knowing what wires to separate would help identify which one is at fault, unless of course they're both dead.

For my own reputation and to make sure I don't completely get you hurt or otherwise cause harm towards you or anyone else here, I won't speculate which wire is what.  I will also have to say that doing any of this most certainly voids any express or implied warranty from a manufacture. I do not recommend this course of action in a workplace environment and do not take responsibility if damages are caused due to circumstances out of my direct control.  IE: You wire a new fan in backwards and the motherboard shorts out.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the long and thorough answer. Finally after hours of troubleshooting and fixes got my server working again.
So firstly I found a solution online that maybe I can disable fan checking from BIOS but that wasn't possible because the hardware check and shutdown was before BIOS was available.
Secondly I switched my fans around to make sure no motherboard connector was broken - all were fine.

Comment: Thirdly I opened the fan (there were 2 plastic "holders" on both sides - those needed to be lifted with a screwdriver to open the fan). Yes there were two fans and both fans had 4 wires connected into them. So the first thing I tried was adding spray oil where the motor rotating end was visible. When doing that I discovered that one of the wires was loose/not connected. So that was the problem - the red wire (most likely power) was disconnected. It was really difficult to solder it back so I removed a bit of the plastic so I had more room to solder it.

Comment: Since it was a really small gap where I could work the first try I got it connected it overlapped a bit with the wire next to it so the server didn't start at all. I scraped the excess tin away and finally got it working. Also the server isn't in like a datacenter and the warranty is long over so the only options were to try and fix it and risk breaking it and still buy new fan or just buy a new one. I also made some screenshots along the if you're interested seeing what it looks inside, let me know.

Comment: And also indeed one fan of the 2 combined was broken.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work! It's legitimately my only answer to anything on superuser right now too.  Also of note is that the datasheet only shows two fans with two wires into each one. Very odd how the same part number is reused by this company over and over and over again.  Would be less odd if it had revisions but alas nothing to be found on google about these.  Glad you got it to work.